# Photon-Photon-Graviton vertex derivation

Tags: quantum-gravity

I have to calculate the scattering amplitude of a photon $\gamma$ and a scalar field $\phi$ interacting through a graviton and I'm having trouble with the photon-photon-graviton vertex calculation.

I am taking the Lagrangian of electrodynamics in curved spactime $\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{-g}\left(-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\right)$ and my stress energy tensor is then :
$$T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}=\frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma}-F_{\mu\lambda}{F}{_\nu^\lambda}$$
(My metric convention is $(-,+,+,+)$)

Because i'm considering $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+\kappa h_{\mu\nu}$, at zeroth order in $h_{\mu\nu}$ my stress-energy tensor is just :
$$T^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{4}\eta_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma}-F_{\mu\lambda}{F}{_\nu^\lambda}$$
Writing now the mode expansion for the four potential
$$A^\mu(x)=\sum_\lambda\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\vec{p}}}}\left[\epsilon^\mu(\vec{p},\lambda)a_\lambda(\vec{p})e^{ip\cdot x}+\epsilon^{\mu\star}(\vec{p},\lambda)a_\lambda^\dagger(\vec{p})e^{-ip\cdot x}\right]$$
with $\epsilon^\mu(\vec{p},\lambda)$ denoting the polarisation of the photon and $\lambda$ going from 1 to 4 (without the gauge condition).
After some tedious calculations, I get the matrix element for ingoing photon with momentum $p_1$ and outgoing photon with momentum $p_2$ :
$$
\begin{align}
<p_1,\lambda\lvert T^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}\rvert p_2,\kappa>=&\frac{\eta_{\mu\nu}}{2}\left[(p_1\cdot p_2)(\epsilon^\star(\vec{p}_1,\lambda)\cdot\epsilon(\vec{p}_2,\kappa))-(p_1\cdot\epsilon(\vec{p}_2,\kappa))(p_2\cdot\epsilon^\star(\vec{p}_1,\lambda))\right]\\
&-p^1_\mu p^2_\nu (\epsilon^\star(\vec{p}_1,\lambda)\cdot\epsilon(\vec{p}_2,\kappa))
-\epsilon^\star_{\mu}(\vec{p}_1,\lambda)\epsilon_{\nu}(\vec{p}_2,\kappa)(p_1\cdot p_2)\\
&+p^1_\mu\epsilon_{\nu}(\vec{p}_2,\kappa)(\epsilon^\star(\vec{p}_1,\lambda)\cdot p_2)+\epsilon^\star_{\mu}(\vec{p}_1,\lambda)p^2_\nu(p_1\cdot\epsilon(\vec{p}_2,\kappa))\\
&+\left[(p_1,\lambda)\leftrightarrow(p_2,\kappa)\right]
\end{align}$$
My vertex should finally read :
$$V_{\mu\nu}=\left(-i\frac{\kappa}{2}\right)<p_1,\lambda\lvert T^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}\rvert p_2,\kappa>$$

Is my answer correct ? In this case, the problem I have now is that I have all these polarisation vectors and I don't quite see how to simplify them, since in all the classical formulas I know from QED for instance we have sums of $\epsilon^{\mu\star}(\vec{p},\lambda)\epsilon^{\nu}(\vec{p},\lambda)$ on $\lambda$, but here I have two different polarisations and two different vectors $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$, so I don't get how to simplify.
I found in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286190/photon-photon-gravitational-scattering) a much more compact expression, but I don't understand how to simplify mine to arrive to this.
I'm not very used to amplitude calculations with gravitons, so maybe I overlooked something very simple.